# Integreate Node js With Stripe

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

I have a website which is **multivendor**, I am using stripe payment gateway for our website, and I have to charge the customer and transfer 5% of the amount of the total product price to the admin and transfer remaining amount to the vendor account. But I am not sure how to use stripe to do that, Below is the example of what I want actually,

I have a product worth $5, I have to charge customer credit card with $5 and transfer 5% means $0.25 to admin account & 4.75 into vendor account, So how can I do that.

Can anyone help me to solve the issue, please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Stripe connect for this.

Below are the steps to achieve this in Stripe.

1. **Vendor onboarding process**
    In this process, the vendor has to connect his Stripe account to Platform account which is you. In this process, you will get Stripe account Id of vendor and you will get required permission to do a checkout on behalf of a user
2. **Now choose the checkout process which suits your needs**

   (Direct charges, Destination charges, Separate charges and transfers). From your requirement, it seems to direct charges so that vendor will responsible for all transaction charges and you will get application fee on each transaction
3. Now you can create charges By specifying application fee and connected account's Id.
   You can refer [here](https://stripe.com/docs/connect) for more details

Here is code snippet in ruby you will use to charge

```
Stripe.api_key = "sk_test_4eC39HqLyjWDarjtT1zdp7dc"

charge = Stripe::Charge.create({
  :amount => 1000,

  :currency => "usd",

  :source => "tok_visa",

  :application_fee => 123,

}, :stripe_account => "{CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID}")
```

Here are few more resources from where you can learn this

https://simpleprogrammer.com/stripe-connect-ultimate-guide/

https://medium.com/@noodlio/stripe-connect-tutorial-how-to-start-accepting-payments-on-behalf-of-your-users-while-charging-a-5bfc1b5e4294

Comment: Sorry, But i didn't understood it. Can you provide any link or resource from which i can easily understand the process. Thanks.

Comment: yes go through this link and try to understand all words carefully 
https://stripe.com/docs/connect

I have done the same for my previous 2 Organizations

Comment: Stripe's documentation is so much useful that you don't need any external resource to do integrate their features

Comment: although i have updated my answer to include more resources on that

Comment: Thanks, But i can't understand why some people's downvoted to my question, They are the worst peoples.

Comment: its because you could have searched this by your self. Stripe's Document is self-sufficient. If my answer helps you can accept that